# titanium fire the filter of the searchbar programmatically

Tags: listview, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, searchbar

I want to filter a `ListView` programmatically from one controller to another. What already tried is:

```
if(args.search){
    $.search.value = args.search;
    $.search.fireEvent('change');
}
```

placed into the second controller.

but even if the value of the `SearchBar` is changed correctly, the change event doesn't popup up the keyboard and filter the rows.

Also tried the other searchbar events.

Answer (score 0):

The worst solution, but works, I found is:

```
if(args.search){
    var first = true;
    $.search.focus();
    $.search.addEventListener('focus',function(){
        if(first){ 
            $.search.value = args.search;
            $.search.blur();
            first = false;
            $.search.focus();
        }
    });
}
```

hope this helps